# convert from year-month-date to year-Quarter in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, where one column(first_date) contains date in the following format:
`2018-03-31`

```
#I have created a monthly level data using the below code
    dataset['first_date']=pd.to_datetime(dataset['first_date']) 
    dataset['first_date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m'))
    **output: 2018-03**
```

**My Question**:​ using first_date I want to create a new column, to get the year & quarter.
output something like **2018-Q1** and must be in string not in **periods**

Comment: IIUC `df['first_date'].dt.to_period('Q')`

Comment: from your code I am getting 2018Q1, can you add "-" in between year and Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['first_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['first_date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
df['quarter'] = pd.to_datetime(df['first_date']).dt.to_period('Q').astype(str).str.replace('Q', '-Q')
print(df)

 first_date  quarter
0    2018-03  2018-Q1
1    2018-03  2018-Q1
2    2018-03  2018-Q1
3    2018-03  2018-Q1
4    2018-03  2018-Q1
5    2018-05  2018-Q2
6    2018-09  2018-Q3
```